# Affine Set Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm working through Lay's *Linear Algebra and its Applications,* and I have just reached Chapter 8, *the Geometry of Vector Spaces.* The current section is Affine Combinations. Thus far, an affine set has been described as one where $(1-t){\bf{p}}+t{\bf{q}}\in S$ for ${\bf{p,q}}\in S$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then comes along 'Theorem 2:' 
[image]

What I gather from this is that 'S is affine if S is affine.' This is remarkably circular to me -- essentially, I don't understand this theorem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: aff $S$ is the affine closure of $S$, which may not equal $S$.  For example, if $S = \{0, 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then aff $S = [0,1] \neq S$ and so $S$ is not affine.  Oops - confused convex hull and affine closure - see comment below.

Comment: $\operatorname{aff}(S)=\{x:\ \exists t\in\mathbb{R}, \exists p,q\in S,\ tp+(1-t)q=x\}$, which doesn't talk about the condition on being affine. Namely, $S=\operatorname{aff}(S)$.

Comment: @AdamJaffe The affine closure of $\{0,1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$. You computed the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Convex_hull_of_a_finite_point_set).

Comment: Well, actually you have to see what is given as definition in that text. The one I gave could be considered a consequence of the definition if another equivalent characterization was used there. For example, they could have defined $\operatorname{aff}(S)$ to be the smallest affine set containing $S$.

Answer (score 0):

In my reading, the theorem is about being closed under *binary affine combinations* implies being closed under *arbitrary finite* affine combinations (i.e. $x_i\in S\implies \sum_i\alpha_ix_i\in S$ whenever $\sum_i\alpha_i=1$).

And, for the proof, induction should be used.